# Why does this boolean compile in C++ and not in Java?

Tags: java, c++

In C++, this expression will compile, and when ran, will print `test`:

```
    if(!1 >= 0) cout<<"test";
```

but in Java, this will not compile:

```
    if(!1 >= 0) System.out.println("test");
```

and instead parentheses are needed:

```
    if(!(1>=0)) System.out.println("test");
```

but `test` will not print since `1 >= 0` is true, and `NOT` true is false.

So why does it compile AND print out `test` in C++, even though the statement is false, but not in Java?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This occurs because `!1` is valid in C++ but not in Java<sup>1</sup>.

Both languages parse `!1>=0` as `(!1)>=0` because (in both C+ and Java) `!` has as higher precedence than `>=`.

So (in C++), `(!1)>=0`-> `0>=0` -> `true` but (in Java) `!1` (`!int`) is a type error.

However (in either C++ or Java), `!(1>=0)` -> `!(true)` -> `false`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Java *only* defines the `!` operator over the `boolean` type.

Answer (score 6):

In java unary operator `!` has high precedence than conditional operator `>=`. That why it needs parenthesis  `()`.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) is the details table of operator precedence of Java.

But, In C++ positive value in condition refer as `boolean true` value. So, `if(!1>=0)` is valid in C++ but invalid in Java. In Java, `boolean` value is only `true` and `false`. It never treat positive value as true.

Comment: In C++ the `!` operator also has higher precedence than `>=`.

Comment: Not just positive values are true, negative values too.  The only non-true value is 0.